# Can't Delete file created via Docker

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I used a docker image to run a program on our school's server using this command.

```
 docker run -t -i -v /target/new_directory 990210oliver/mycc.docker:v1 /bin/bash
```

After I ran it it created a firectory on my account called new_directory. Now I don't have permissions to delete or modify the files.

How do I remove this directory?

Comment: for me stoping docker and deleting the file manually, worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the owner of all the files on the directory to your used ID within the container running as root, then exit the container and remove the directory.

```
docker run --rm -v /target/new_directory 990210oliver/mycc.docker:v1 chown -R $(id -un):$(id -un) /target/new_directory
exit
rm -rf $HOME/new_directory
```

Answer (score 26):

I also had this problem.

After:

```
docker run --name jenkins -p 8080:8080 -v $HOME/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home jenkins jenkins
```

I couldn't remove files in `$HOME/jenkins`.

[Ricardo Branco's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42424302) didn't work for me because `chown` gave me:

```
chown: changing ownership of '/var/jenkins_home': Operation not permitted
```

**Solution:**

`exec /bin/bash` into container as a root user:

```
docker exec -it --privileged --user root container_id /bin/bash
```

then:

```
cd /var/jenkins_home/ && rm -r * .*
```

Comment: what if the the contrainer, in which I created the folder, has been deleted?

Comment: Then run another similar container, and within it, I guess you would have the necessary permissions to delete what was created by the previous one.

Answer (score 5):

I made @siulkilulki's answer into one line:

```
docker exec --privileged --user root <CONTAINER_ID> chown -R "$(id -u):$(id -g)" <TARGET_DIR>
```

Note that here the CONTAINER must be up.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I am using ubuntu 18.04. I ran the following code and then I was able to delete files locally. I have `app` dir inside docker project dir

1. cd to your docker project dir
2. `sudo chown -R $(whoami):$(whoami) app/`

Comment: this assumes you have access to sudo, the question is relevant when you don't

Answer (score 0):

docker run -v {absolute path to dir with the file}:/to_delete -it ubuntu /bin/bash

Then just:

$ cd to_delete

$ rm -rf <file/dir>

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that does not require `--privileged`.

### Game Plan

1. Determine UIDs of all offending files created by previous docker runs.  Use docker to find them, since in-container UID is not the same as host UID.  An **offending file** is any file not owned by container user **root** which maps to the current user running docker.
2. Run a container using each discovered UID and delete the offending files (or chown them).

### Code

```bash
# Assumes that current dir is the volume
# find files owned by docker internal uuids (not root) on the mounted volume:
BAD_FILE_UIDS=$(docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/build alpine sh -c 'find /build -mindepth 1 -not -user root | xargs stat -c "%u" | sort -u')
if [ -n "${BAD_FILE_UIDS}" ] ; then
  for uuid in $BAD_FILE_UIDS ; do
    echo "Cleaning up files owned by $uuid using docker"
    docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/build --user $uuid:0 alpine find /build -mindepth 1 -user $uuid -delete
  done
fi
```

You can change the `-delete` to `-exec chown SOME_USER {} \;` to chown.

The above works well for use in CI as post-build cleanup.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
docker stop $CONTAINER_NAME
docker rm -v $CONTAINER_NAME
```

I guess this should remove the mounted dir. If it doesn't, do this explicitly:

```
sudo rm -rf /target/new_directory
```

Comment: `docker rm -v container_name` don't delete bind mount volumes.
OP said that he "don't have permissions to delete or modify the files" so `sudo rm -rf /target/new_directory` is useless