# Permission denied - Unlink file

Tags: php, docker, nginx, supervisord

I can upload a file but not delete it.

I have a nginx, laravel, and redis containers.

When I upload my queue create files and folders into /var/www/storage/app/public (laravel container)

This folder is share with the host by a docker volume.

When I try to remove the file and the folder I can't because I don't have permissions...

I tried to change php-fpm user from www-data to root in www.conf
I tried to launch supervisord queue process and fpm as root user

www.conf

```
; Unix user/group of processes
; Note: The user is mandatory. If the group is not set, the default user's group
;       will be used.
user = www-data
group = www-data
```

supervisord.conf

```
[program:php-fpm]
command=/usr/local/sbin/php-fpm -F
autostart=true
autorestart=true
priority=5
stdout_events_enabled=true
stderr_events_enabled=true

[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/artisan queue:work redis --sleep=3 --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
numprocs=8
priority=10
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/storage/logs/worker.log
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution so if some one of you have this kind of issue.

I finnally change user of Redis in my supervisord conf
to match the user conf of php fpm (so www-data instead of root)

Tada it’s works fine

Answer (score 0):

I understand your cant remove files or folder in container, maybe you can see: [Can't Delete file created via Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42423999/cant-delete-file-created-via-docker)

Comment: Yeah sure, because my php process worked as www-data and my container as root maybe that's the problem.. but I don't want to do a chown each time I create a file according to your link.. do you understand ?

Comment: The link mean you can chown when you are create container, not each time.Maybe you can see again

Comment: ha yes I'll try it